# Powershell not loading profile when running through PSEXEC

Tags: powershell, profile, powershell-1.0, psexec

I am working with powershell 1.0 using PSEXEC to run scripts remotely (or on the same box in a batch mode).  On my machine, the "remoted" powershell session correctly loads my profile.ps1 (from the MyDocuments folder), but on another machine, it doesn't.  I'm not passing in the -noprofile switch to the powershell.exe, and I have verified that the powershell session is in fact network-authenticated (I had it hit an admin share on a server and that worked just fine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind.  Different PSEXEC version running on the other machine.